# cors policy error on express axios get method - error 503

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, ionic-framework, http-status-code-503

I'm trying to pass throught cors policy using nodejs + express in an heroku api, but getting this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://....' from origin 'https://...' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

My methods in the frontend are:

```js
const fetchUser = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(
      process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + `/api/user/${userId}`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer  + ${token}`,
        },
      },
    )

    console.log(res.data)
    setStatsInit({ waiting: false, stats: res.data })
  }
```

in server:

```js
const corsOptions = {
  origin: true,
  methods: ['GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'OPTIONS', 'DELETE'],
  headers: [
    'Content-Type',
    'Authorization',
    'application/json',
    'text/plain',
    '*/*',
  ],
  credentials: true,
  maxAge: 3600,
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.get('/api/user/:uid', middleware.decodeTokenContext, async (req, res) => {
  const user = {
    uid: req.params.uid,
  }
  const userStats = await FirestoreClient.getByPath(`users/${user.uid}`)

  return res.json({ userStats })
})
```

The middleware, to check if it is authenticated:

```js
async decodeTokenContext(req, res, next) {
    let token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]

    try {
      const decodeValue = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token)
      if (decodeValue) {

        return next()
      }
      return res.json({ message: 'Não autorizado' })
    } catch (e) {
      return res.json({ message: 'Erro Interno' })
    }
  }
```

on the network, on browser, i got this error:

[image]

How to solve that error of cors?

Comment: try changing origin: true, to origin: "*", see documentation https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html for cors options in middleware

Comment: @Nonik what's wrong with `true`? From the documentation... _"Boolean - set origin to true to reflect the request origin, as defined by `req.header('Origin')`"_

Comment: Are you sure your API is deployed and available? Can you hit it with Postman? 503 typically means a service is not accepting requests

Comment: @Phil you are correct. I'm trying to fix.